# How can I read the content of a form-data when the response is in html(Swift)

Tags: swift, forms, url, postman, http-post

I'm building an iOS application and I need to access the information on a website. I've located the API endpoint, and was able to get a result in Postman
[screenshot of API header and form data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RsEr.jpg)

So far I have this code which can allow me to make the request, but how do I parse the response(which is an HTML form, then display response in app

````
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        urlRequest.setValue("application/form-data",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "year=2021&season=Outdoor&province=ON&age_group=OPEN&age_sub_group_masters=ALL&age_sub_group_para=ALL&rankings_event=100m&best_by_athlete=1&rankings_event_spec_num=1&is_relay_EVENT=0&page=1"
        urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        
        urlRequest = .init(url: url!)```
````

Comment: Here is an [example](https://github.com/egorskikh/picturesflow8/tree/main/picturesflow8/Random%20Pictures/Networking) get request

Comment: @ekkeee I can make the request, but do you know how to parse the response?

Comment: When you make a request, what comes to you? Show it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a great resources that showed how to send POST Request with post body, and how to read the response

[How To send POST Request](https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/http-post-request-example-in-swift/)

Now it's just a matter of parsing the HTML that is returned, and displaying it in app.

```
        let url = URL(string: Constants.rankingAPI)
        guard let requestUrl = url else {
            fatalError()
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        let postString = "year=2021&season=Outdoor&province=ON&age_group=OPEN&age_sub_group_masters=ALL&age_sub_group_para=ALL&rankings_event=100m&best_by_athlete=1&rankings_event_spec_num=1&is_relay_EVENT=0&page=1"
        
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            
            // Check for Error
            if let error = error {
                print("Error took place \(error)")
                return
            }
            
            // Convert HTTP Response Data to a String
            if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Response data string:\n \(dataString.htmlToString)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```